# Quiz application using PHP, MySql, Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

I am planning to make quiz web application for one of my friend.
I have decided on the below as of now. I need your suggestions on this and what can be changed so that in can help in making the application more optimized.

Database - **MySql**

Backend - **PHP**

Frontend - **Bootstrap,HTML,JSS,CSS**

So the application would be like there can be tests related to one topic.
A test can contain 10 questions. All will be multiple choice questions.

I am planning to show 10 questions on one page and a submit button that will submit the quiz once all questions are answered.

On next page it will show the user correct option along with the option he highlighted. Can also add option to send correct answers to their emailid.

**On database side**
i thought of following tables

**questions** - contain columns like question_id,text,option1,option2,option3,option4,correct_option.

**category** - list of categories. columns - cat_id,cat_name

**questions_category** - relation between question and category. columns - question_id,cat_id

I am confused here like how/where the correct_option should be stored. Should it be the column_name(option1 etc)/ or the full answer text. Any other idea?

Also, thought of accessing database records using **REST** api. I found **Slim framework** for creating REST api in php. I chose this method, because in future if i want to change database or frontend, it will be easier.

Or do you think it is Ok not to use REST?

In frontend, i am planning to do **AJAX** calls to respective apis to access the questions etc and return the response in JSON format.

Thing i don't like here it to create the HTML structure from JSON to show the data in proper format. Would not this be very cluttered part in javascript files.

Is there any way i can avoid it ? or some other way to achieve the same.

Please give suggestions about the above, what can be changed to make it more efficient.

Comment: i Suggest to use php, mysql, extjs 4, json to complete this whole thing in a day. with very less effort

Comment: An idea about the correct option thing: Always store the correct answer in option1 and shuffle the answers on displaying. You could save yourself the correct_option column this way

Comment: I down voted your question because of multiple things, the ones worth mentioning would be that I find that your question is very broad, as you try to cover multiple things at once. Also the question seems to be asking for the best way to solve things (Primarily opinion-based/Recommend tool/software/library).

Comment: @epodax yes i agree it is bit broad. See i don't have much experience in php. So i was just asking is there any other effective way which experience persons can tell. so instead of wasting my time implement this solution, it would be better if i get more appropriate solution to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

I would change the schema of your table.

First table is `category` with columns

```
cat_id  |  cat_name
```

Second table is `question` with columns

```
question_id  |  cat_id  |  question
```

Third table is `options` with columns

```
option_id  |  question_id  |  option  |  correct
```

The relation of `question` table with the `category` table is the `cat_id`. Then the relation of question table to options table is `question_id`.

You'll be storing your multiple options in the options table. What if suddenly, you want to have more options for a question? Then this schema would work for you. Then for the `correct` column, `1` would trigger a correct answer and `0` for wrong one.

For example:

category table:

```
cat_id  |  cat_name
  1     |    fruits
```

question table:

```
question_id  |  cat_id  |  question
    1        |     1    |  What is the color of apple?
    2        |     1    |  What fruit is good for potassium?
```

options table:

```
option_id  |  question_id  |  option  |  correct
   1       |      1        |   red    |     1
   2       |      1        |   blue   |     0
   3       |      1        |  yellow  |     0
   4       |      1        |  magenta |     0
   5       |      2        |  apple   |     0
   6       |      2        |  banana  |     1
   7       |      2        |  mango   |     0
   8       |      2        |  melon   |     0
```

So when you fetch a question, you can use `INNER JOIN` to get the options/answer, or filter it with category.

```
SELECT a.question, b.cat_name, c.question_id, c.option, c.correct
  FROM question a
  INNER JOIN category b ON a.cat_id = b.cat_id
  INNER JOIN options c FROM a.question_id = c.question_id
  WHERE b.cat_id = ?
```

Comment: Thanks for the schema. I would really appreciate if you give your views on the REST api method also, is this the good way or shall i directly access database using php?